# How to get Lilliput USB monitor working?

Tags: xorg, display, displaylink

Okay, I just got a [Lilliput 7" USB Monitor](https://web.archive.org/web/20120904104215/http://www.thinkgeek.com:80/computing/usb-gadgets/c609):

[image]
<sub>(source: [thinkgeek.com](https://www.thinkgeek.com/images/products/frontsquare/c609_lilliput_mini_usb_monitor.jpg))</sub>

Unfortunately, I am having some trouble getting it to work in Ubuntu.

It is a [DisplayLink](https://www.displaylink.com/) device, so it should work in Ubuntu.

Here is the output of `lsusb`:

> ...
> Bus 002 Device 007: ID 17e9:02a9 Newnham Research
> ...

I modified my `xorg.conf` file to accommodate the device.

```
# nvidia-settings: X configuration file generated by nvidia-settings
# nvidia-settings:  version 1.0  (buildd@yellow)  Fri Apr  9 11:51:21 UTC 2010

# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 1.0  (buildmeister@builder58)  Fri Mar 12 02:12:40 PST 2010

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "DisplayLinkScreen" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen0" RightOf "DisplayLinkScreen"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    Option         "Xinerama" "0"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"

    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "LPL"
    HorizSync       30.0 - 75.0
    VertRefresh     60.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "BenQ T705"
    HorizSync       31.0 - 83.0
    VertRefresh     56.0 - 76.0
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400M GS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName      "GeForce 8400M GS"
    BusID          "PCI:1:0:0"
    Screen          1
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "DFP: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen1"
    Device         "Device1"
    Monitor        "Monitor1"
    DefaultDepth    24
    Option         "TwinView" "0"
    Option         "metamodes" "CRT: nvidia-auto-select +0+0"
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

#################################################

Section "Files"
ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
ModulePath      "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules"
ModulePath      "/usr/local/lib/xorg/modules/drivers"
EndSection

############### DisplayLink Stuff ###############
Section "Device"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkDevice"
    driver          "displaylink"
    Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkScreen"
    Device          "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Monitor         "DisplayLinkMonitor"
    DefaultDepth    16
    SubSection "Display"
        Depth   16
        Modes   "800×480"
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

All I get is a green screen.

**Any** tips or advice would be appreciated!

---

**Update:** I discovered that X11 was having trouble finding the `displaylink_drv.so` module, so I fixed that. Then my XServer completely crashed. (Segmentation fault, I believe.)

Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Gee... I wonder where that [came from](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/stack-exchange-api-contest-winners/). Congratulations!

Comment: @Dennis: Haha. Thanks. I sort of got it working now :)

Comment: Present best answers are at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually working... and I all did was restore `xorg.conf.backup`. Weird. Oh well.

Comment: Excellent! :D (If this was Facebook I'd like it...)

Comment: Present best answers are at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version

Answer (score 1):

There is a quite [detailed blog post](http://karuppuswamy.com/wordpress/2010/07/19/how-to-get-lilliput-displaylink-based-usb-monitor-um-70-17e902a9-working-in-ubuntu-linux/) from July 2010 - it certainly seems more complicated than it should be, and not quite a perfect outcome either.

Comment: I followed that post step-by-step :) Doesn't work at all... though I do get the green screen. Any diagnostic information? Is there an IRC channel that would be good to get help with this on?

Comment: @george #ubuntu or ##linux on freenode are the only channels I can think of exploring.

Comment: @aperson: I asked on #ubuntu - but a guy there just told me to file a bug :)

Comment: Thi is a re=post from an existing article I used in the past, but My X was also crashing. That was under Ubuntu 10.04. I did not have time to try it under Ubuntu 10.10. I was hoping that 10.10 would solve this better than hacking in the X.org file.

Answer (score 1):

Displaylink added Open Source on their support/feedback forum.
[DisplayLink drivers Open Source](http://www.displaylink.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=29)

I hope this will open up some better solutions and support for these DisplayLink USB displays.