# Modules aren't loading - or something even more serious is wrong

Tags: boot, kernel, modules, blacklist

I am trying to solve [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3348/how-to-get-lilliput-usb-monitor-running-in-ubuntu) problem. In the process, I messed up the kernel configuration and some of the modules aren't loading.

Whenever I start *that particular kernel*, I get a message saying "Module `nvidia` could not be found." This of course means the USB module isn't working either. No mouse.

Thankfully I had another kernel installed that I'm using now - but I'd like my other one back.

I can remember some of the steps I took - I edited some of the arguments being passed to the kernel - but I just got rid of those by editing the line when GRUB started - and it still didn't fix anything. The only other thing I remember is messing with `initramfs`.

How would I go about fixing that? I can boot to a console, but I'm not very familiar with any command-line text editors. Is there a way to fix this from the kernel I'm using right now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a working kernel, I'd say the easiest route to success is the Etch-A-Sketch approach. Boot into the working kernel, remove the broken kernel, nuke its `/lib/modules/<kernel-version>` (or `/lib64/`) dir and when it's all dead, reinstall the kernel.

If you need to target the issue, check the logs. `/var/log/kern.log` *should* show up module loader explosions IIRC.

Comment: Yup. Worked just fine. All I did was remove it with synaptic and reinstalled it.