# How to connect USB monitor?

Tags: usb, monitor, displaylink

I have a Mimo monitor and it runs USB. I tried and failed and I don't know what to do......All i get from the USB screen is just a green screen. Anyone could help me?

Comment: Present best answers are at http://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version

Answer (score 2):

You will need to install the xserver-xorg-video-displaylink package to get support for this class of devices (identifiable by connecting via USB and presenting a green screen on successful initialisation).  The X server does not currently support hotplug events on the USB bus, so you will need to create an xorg.conf file to use such a device.  An example xorg.conf file is included in the package (under /usr/share/doc/xserver-xorg-video-displaylink/examples).

If the above is not working for you, please file a bug against xserver-xorg-video-displaylink: there may be some variation between displaylink devices, which may not be handled completely by the existing driver (but any such lack of support is a bug to be fixed, rather than a result of user error).