# Targus usb 3.0 docking station support

Tags: drivers, graphics, displaylink

I am planning to purchase a Targus 3.0 docking station, does anybody have experience with it on Ubuntu.

Will the display work?

http://www.targus.com/uk/CategorySearch.asp?SearchedTerms=usb+docking+station&Action.x=0&Action.y=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have the Targus USB 3.0 Dual Video Docking Station, recently purchased. I bought it with a Dell XPS 13 ("Sputnik"), and it works for USB, Ethernet with this Dell Ultrabook.

The sound out does not work (I haven't tested microphone).
The video out does not work with the supplied connectors for either the HDMI or DVI ports. I believe that there are some 'code enhancement opportunities' for USB3 video and Ubuntu.

The Dell machine is running 12.04LTS: 3.2.0-29-generic #46+kamal5~DellXPS-Ubuntu SMP Sun Jul 29 18:49:08 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux.

Comment: ah, thank you for the answer, I was really hoping that the video will work

Comment: This answer is now obsolete, read Justaman's answer below.

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm that the displaylink driver works. I just bought the "Targus ACP71USZ USB 3 Docking Station with HD Video and Power Adapter" and I have installed the drivers (version 1.0.138) as instructed at

http://support.displaylink.com/knowledgebase/articles/615714#ubuntu

Things so far have worked out smoothly in my Ubuntu 15.04 system. Configuration through the gnome system settings has been easy.
I have encountered only one minor glitch. The speakers do not work through the docking station. Surprisingly, in the sound settings the Targus microphone input is detected but the output is not. Not a deal breaker, though.

Comment: This is not an answer to this question at all. Please ask your question separately or to follow this question mark it as favourite.

Comment: Actually, it's exactly related.  The Targus station requires DisplayLink drivers.  This helped me figure out how to set up displays.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: DisplayLink now provides drivers for ubuntu [here](http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu). Last time I checked (several months ago tbh), it worked, but was using quite a lot of CPU.

Displaylink drivers for usb 3.0 is not implemented for linux. See http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showthread.php?t=1748

Especially, an official says they have no plan to release it anytime soon :
http://www.displaylink.org/forum/showpost.php?p=8935&postcount=23

But if you have time, participating in making the support for usb2.0 displaylink better might make them change their point of view, see post 35 (can't link here, because not enough rep).

Comment: I edited. But please note that in this case, I DID provide an answer («not supported yet»), which is the equivalent to "It is the next building over" in the answer you've linked and different of the mere «please see this <random link>»

Comment: I was being pedantic to suggest you make your answer slightly more complete on this site in case the link expires/changes, point taken, keep up the good work! :)

Answer (score 1):

For me :

- ethernet connection : ok
- sound out : ok
- hub usb : ok
- display : not    working

Here is my xrandr output:

```
$ xrandr 
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
eDP1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 294mm x 165mm
   1920x1080      60.0*+   59.9     40.0  
   [...]
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

It seems to see the display but not the connection !

Comment: any way we can ask for a official response?

Comment: For the display, see http://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version/393117#393117

Answer (score 1):

" Below is the latest download from DisplayLink for Ubuntu distributions. This release has been prepared to be compatible with Ubuntu 14.04.x LTS and 16.04 LTS. Other variants and editions may be compatible if they meet minimum O/S requirements, but are not supported by DisplayLink. Please see our support page for information on how to install this driver on Ubuntu."

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

Comment: Does display link have anything to do with the targus docking station?

Comment: I updated the drivers from there and everything worked on Targus USB 3.0 Docking Station. Thanks @Justaman!

Answer (score 0):

the manufacturer should be **"DisplayLink"**
Linux driver are WIP 
check: http://libdlo.freedesktop.org and discussion on http://www.displaylink.org/forum/forumdisplay.php?f=29

Comment: Yes and no. You are right, DisplayLink is the company providing the chips that offer the graphics solution, but actual products are offered from a lot of brands. A friend bought one from Lenovo last year and I was lucky to get one for a cheap price from HP recently.

Comment: [They seem to be doing now](https://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like DisplayLink will not develop proper drivers for Linux [until enough interest is shown.](https://www.change.org/petitions/displaylink-support-linux-with-dl-3000-series-chips)

sic. "[...]DisplayLink has refused to support linux or the community until sufficient interest is shown, or there's better linux "support for the DL-1x5[...]"