# DisplayLink usb on ubuntu 12.04 on laptop

Tags: 12.04, xorg, multiple-monitors, dualhead, displaylink

I'd like to use a displaylink usb UGA-2k-A rev b. (dl-195) on my laptop with ubuntu 12.04
I have an Asus x53s with intel graphics and nvidia Geforce GT 520MX 1GB.
I've read a lot of posts about how to config, but my problem still persist.

I've installed the xserver-xorg-displaylink driver.
The monitor goes green, but I still have problem with my xorg.conf
This is my last try.

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "DisplayLinkScreen" 1280 0
    Screen      1  "Screen0" RightOf "DisplayLinkScreen"
        Option         "Xinerama" "off" 
EndSection
Section "ServerFlags"
    Option       "RandR" "on"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
Identifier   "Monitor0"
VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
Identifier  "Card0"
Driver      "intel"
BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
Identifier "Screen0"
Device     "Card0"
Monitor    "Monitor0"
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     1
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     4
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     8
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     15
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     16
EndSubSection
SubSection "Display"
    Viewport   0 0
    Depth     24
EndSubSection
EndSection

############### DisplayLink Stuff ###############                                                                 

Section "Device"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkDevice"
    driver          "displaylink"
    Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkMonitor"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier      "DisplayLinkScreen"
Device          "DisplayLinkDevice"
    Monitor         "DisplayLinkMonitor"
   # SubSection "Display"
   #         Depth   24
   #        Modes   "1280x1024"
   # EndSubSection
EndSection
```

And this is the result...https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByBQOgnmD50pcS1PYTZ1WlJCSGc/edit?usp=sharing

Where is my fault?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't the first displaylink question we've had.  I'ld really like to know about someone that got a particular one working.  If you do, please ping me in the comments with a purchase point.

Comment: An intermediate step is putting a static image on the device, as in this answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/393117/46709

Answer (score 0):

```
#/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/52-displaylink.conf
Section "Device"
   Identifier      "intel"
   driver          "intel"
   Option "monitor-LVDS1" "monitor2"
   Option "monitor-VGA1" "monitor1"
EndSection

Section "Device"
   Identifier      "dl1"
   driver          "displaylink"
   Option  "fbdev" "/dev/fb1"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "monitor0"
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "monitor1"
   Option "RightOf" "monitor2"
   Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
   Identifier "monitor2"
   Option "PreferredMode" "1366x768"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "screen0"
   Device "dl1"
   Monitor "monitor0"
   DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "Screen"
   Identifier "screen1"
   Device "intel"
   Monitor "monitor1"
   DefaultDepth 16
EndSection

Section "ServerLayout"
   Identifier     "multihead"
   Screen      0  "screen0" 0 0
   Screen      1  "screen1" LeftOf "screen0"
   Option    "Xinerama" "on"
EndSection
```

Comment: This answer seems to be very specific for your case with Intel hardware, etc. It would be a lot better answer if you would explain what is there to edit for a general user (and the OP in this case) specific for the DisplayLink part.