# Lenovo USB Monitor - LT1423p

Tags: usb, lenovo, monitor, displaylink

Morning all,

I have recently aquired a USB Lenovo monitor, LT1423p but it is not working in Ubuntu 13.10.

I have read through the forums and googled like a madman and can find alot of information about displylink but nothing has helped so far.

I have looked through this fix but have not had any luck.

The screen goes straight into powersave mode after being plugged in, so no signal from OS.

The monitor is seen with lsusb:

```
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 090c:3261 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 17e9:4322 DisplayLink
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 0451:8043 Texas Instruments, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

and this is from dmesg:

```
[    5.558512] usb 2-1.1.2: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci-pci
[    5.659538] usb 2-1.1.2: New USB device found, idVendor=17e9, idProduct=4322
[    5.659545] usb 2-1.1.2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    5.659550] usb 2-1.1.2: Product: Lenovo USB Monitor
[    5.659554] usb 2-1.1.2: Manufacturer: DisplayLink
[    5.659557] usb 2-1.1.2: SerialNumber: 1S60A3UAT2EUVN244148
```

This is from the /var/log/syslog file:

```
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.123019] usb 2-1.1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=3261
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.123025] usb 2-1.1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.123029] usb 2-1.1.4: Product: LT1423p
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.123032] usb 2-1.1.4: Manufacturer: Lenovo Corporation
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.123035] usb 2-1.1.4: SerialNumber: AA00000000008208
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.151905] fbcon: inteldrmfb (fb0) is primary device
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.356899] Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x67
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.364591] i915 0000:00:02.0: fb0: inteldrmfb frame buffer device
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.364594] i915 0000:00:02.0: registered panic notifier
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.385937] ACPI: Video Device [GFX0] (multi-head: yes  rom: no  post: no)
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.386248] input: Video Bus as /devices/LNXSYSTM:00/device:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input2
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.388397] [drm] Initialized i915 1.6.0 20080730 for 0000:00:02.0 on minor 0
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.388770] snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1b.0: irq 51 for MSI/MSI-X
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.438105] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input4
Dec 18 13:13:16 project kernel: [    3.438374] input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1b.0/sound/card0/input3
```

Any advice on how to get this screen working will be greatly appreciated, if you need more log info just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You should try to get a static display up first, see instructions at [How can I get a DisplayLink USB monitor work under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version/393117#393117)
Then work on improving the primary question on this topic at:
[How can I get a DisplayLink USB monitor work under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-under-ubuntu-any-recent-version/)