# AOC USB Monitor Support with linux

Tags: drivers, usb, hard-drive, hardware, monitor

I Have linux OS Linux mint 18 SARA! 
I Want to buy for mine laptop the AOC Usb portable monitor 15.6 inch! 
Will it work with such OS ? And Can i install it with any other Debian OS based ?

[The link for such monitor](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBNbGRh1cAY)

Comment: Hi! Since I don't have this kind of device I can only make slight assumptions in this case but I hope this will take you closer to your goal.

http://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-work-under-ubuntu

As far as i can see there is driver support for your monitor, so it should work fine.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To use this device you will need to use the DisplayLink driver

http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu

This works with my displaylink2hdtrio device which i would guess is the same as your screen. The driver looks like it should work with other debian systems

```
amias@rome:~/Downloads$ sudo ./displaylink-driver-1.2.58.run 
Verifying archive integrity... All good.
Uncompressing DisplayLink Linux Driver 1.2.58  100%  
DisplayLink Linux Software 1.2.58 install script called: install
Distribution discovered: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Installing
Configuring EVDI DKMS module
Registering EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Building EVDI kernel module with DKMS
Installing EVDI kernel module to kernel tree
EVDI kernel module built successfully
Installing x64-ubuntu-1604/DisplayLinkManager
Installing libraries
Installing firmware packages
Installing license file
Adding udev rule for DisplayLink DL-3xxx/5xxx devices
```

After this go to the Control Center and you should see an additional monitor when you load the screen settings applet

Something to bare in mind is the refresh rate is really low because of the low data rates of USB2, this meant that connecting this display made all the other displays i use drop down to 30hz which felt horribly laggy compared to the normal 60hz.

You might be able to tweak it a bit with xrandr and cvt but don't expect to show video. Its fine for text mode displays from say a servers framebuffer but its not good for a desktop.

Don't be tempted to unplug this device if this display is still active, it will crash X when its unplugged. You will need to disable the display first.

If you are buying this in the UK you could just try it and return it in accordance with the distance selling regulations, might cost you the postage.

Comment: 4 years later, this did not work on Ubuntu 20.04 LTS with an AOC monitor

Comment: I installed this for  I1659FWUX on ubuntu 220.4 and it says installation completed successfully, but nothing happens. Even after a reboot the USB monitor doesn't turn on