# Ubuntu Compatible USB Monitors

Tags: drivers, multiple-monitors, display, compatibility

In brief:  I'm hoping to obtain a list of portable monitors that people *know* work well with Ubuntu.

In detail: I run Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.  I would like a portable computer monitor (about 15 inches, less than 4 pounds) that is powered by USB (**not C variant though**) and works well with Ubuntu.  By works "well", I mean that using this monitor with Ubuntu doesn't suffer from problems like:

- Accidental disconnection crashes the X system (https://askubuntu.com/a/829870/115100)
- Excessive lag

I also hope to find a monitor that supports basic features like switching between duplicate and extend modes.

A little research on Google has showed the following types of pages:

- Questions about AOC-brand monitors: people seem to need help resolving all manner of driver-related difficulties.  I want to be sure that, if I purchase a display, the driver exists for it.  All the difficulty illustrated in those pages does not give me confidence.
- An Amazon.com comment from a software developer who really likes an ASUS monitor that he or she purchased (ASUS MB169B+ 15.6") and explicitly mentions that it's Ubuntu compatible.  This is the *only* explicit reference I've found to "display works with Ubuntu"

That's just not enough.  Please sound off with what you know!  Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because shopping recommendations are off-topic here.

Comment: A humble response:  To me, the statement that a BMW and Mercedes are both functioning vehicles does not constitute a recommendation of which to buy.  Also, I envision this post being very useful to everybody who is conducting such research in the future (assuming I get many answers), and may appreciate it not being closed.

Comment: that's not what you're asking for here, though. Here you're asking for statements like "a Land Rover and a Jeep are both functioning off-road", which is indeed a recommendation. On top of that you ask if the vehicles in question have power steering or seat warming. More recommendations.

Answer (score 1):

I have an ASUS MB169B+ that works with Ubuntu 16.04 and 17.10 with VirtualBox VMs and native installs. Getting an acceptable display resolution was not a trivial exercise and the result is not perfect.

Performance in the portrait orientation is disappointing.

It's a nice little monitor. Works very well in Windows and there is some effort put to keeping the official driver up to date with Ubuntu. However I suspect that effort is a labor of love, not a business priority.

The standard driver is the DisplayLink: http://www.displaylink.com/downloads/ubuntu,

The standard driver didn't go well for me so I settled on this driver: https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian. I had to hack the install script to make it accept the Ubuntu release but installation went quite smoothly after that.

( UPDATE: I just checked github and the developer has updated the script to 17.10 so the situation may have improved.)

If you don't mind a bit of tinkering, and/or can wait for the drivers to improve... well, that's up to you.