# Ubuntu and docking stations

Tags: dock, docking

I have a Acer Aspire VX with only one video output (HDMI) and a USB type-C port. I'd like to have a dual monitor (so 3 monitors with the laptop's one).
I've seen that the best solution would be to use a usb type C docking station.
I'm just wondering about the comptability of those things with Ubuntu. I didn't find much information about it.
Does anyone use this kind of setup?
CHeers

Comment: Most are compatible as they're just "extensions". Some provide also an "external graphics" based on Displaylink chipsets for which drivers are required but that's all.

Comment: @MichaelBay do I need to make sure I get  a docking station with a DisplayLink chipset, or are there other chipsets and drivers widely available  too?

Answer (score 0):

I have 2 docking stations:

- [Lenovo](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/accessories-and-monitors/docking/usb-docks-universal-cable-docks/TP-USB-C-DOCK-GEN2-US/p/40AS0090US)
- [Dell](https://www.dell.com/en-us/work/shop/dell-docking-station-usb-30-d3100/apd/452-bbpg/pc-accessories)

I would recommend Lenovo. The reason is Lenovo works out of the box. You don't have to install anything, it just works.

Dell required the mentioned in comments DisplayLink driver. There is an official driver for xx.04 versions of Ubuntu. If you upgrade to xx.10 it may stop working unless you downgrade to a specific version of kernel.

There is a workaround, you can use [this github driver](https://github.com/AdnanHodzic/displaylink-debian), which I used before (see my [installation instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-work-under-ubuntu/1118213#1118213)). However I think it is not maintained anymore, so with future kernels, once again you may have problems.

**TL;DR;**

So, clearly having to worry about the drivers or using Lenovo which just works, the choice is clear.

Also note, that Lenovo is now selling some laptops with Ubuntu. This means they are leaning towards this market more. I think they are trying to make their devices compatible with Ubuntu (or linux in general), and I would expect this to also happen with their accessories. I also use their laptop with Ubuntu and everything works perfectly.

Hope this helps.

BTW: Not affiliated with Lenovo :)