# Drivers needed for Ubuntu, ASUS zenbook and SIIG docking station

Tags: drivers, touchpad, asus, docking

I'm new to linux/ubuntu, and I recently purchased an external SIIG docking station and a ASUS zenbook. Booting into an 18.04.1 LTS desktop install on the laptop, two driver issues are evident: 1) the touchpad right-click is not working with the current ubuntu distro provided driver and 2) the driver loading for USB-C (USB 3.1) from the distro only works with the keyboard and mouse through the SIIG docking station. Yes, I've googled linux driver issues although I just want to quickly research (not jump into non-free db update apt-get etc) if drivers are available for these two devices someplace else (community? non-free?). Or do I log the issues with the Ubuntu community for these bugs? Since the distro drivers do seem to recognize the devices, but are only partially functional for both.

I'm having difficulty even identifying what the touch-pad device/manufacturer is on the ASUS zenbook so not even sure where to start/how to research a driver for this guy:

**ASUS ZenBook UX430UN UltraBook Laptop:**
 https://www.asus.com/Laptops/ASUS-ZenBook-UX430UN/HelpDesk_Download/

Docking station info:
**SIIG USB docking station:**
http://www.siig.com/download/search/?keyword=JU-DK0411-S1

I whiped the Ubuntu install and now I am functional with a Windows10Pro host boot, everything works, but I've had to resort to Ubuntu in a virtualbox VM -  this is definitely sub optimal. I'm trying to make the full switch over to linux and I want Windows in the guest VM - so really appreciate any help here.

Comment: For this `the touchpad right-click is not working with the current ubuntu distro`, did you try `two finder right click`?

Comment: If you call `libinput debug-events --verbose`, and then use the right clock — does anything appear? If nothing does, can you repeat it with `evemu-record` *(it will list available HID devices, and prompt you for one to use. Choose the one with "touchpad" in its name)* — does anything appears there for right-clicking the touchpad? *(note: you might need to install some packages for the commands to work; I think it's `evemu-tools` and `libinput-tools`. I.e. use `sudo apt-get install evemu-tools libinput-tools`)*.

Comment: Thanks for replies folks, I'm a little less interested in trying to get the mouse pad working, since the majority of my time I work with external monitors and I really need to get the docking station working.  But it doesn't look like there's any drivers to support the one I mentioned above. What is a good external docking station that supports multiple hi-res monitors that is well supported with Linux drivers? I didn't have any luck trying to find one on Amazon yesterday.

Answer (score 1):

I maintain latest & most featured Asus linux drivers. Included are drivers for numpad/touchpad driver, Asus Pen driver, WMI hotkeys driver (Fn+Fx keys). Link https://github.com/asus-linux-drivers. If any problems persist, please contact me via github contact e-mail or create issue on github repository.

Comment: the OP has not logged in to SE for over 3 years.

Comment: @trondhansen can be helpful for others, problem with Asus linux drivers still persists, unfortunately

Comment: That is not how askubuntu likes to work. This is a comment possibly leading to a fix, not an answer to the problem. Answers are reserved for actual answers to the problem.

Comment: @Rinzwind Read entire question please. Owner asked for drivers for 2 devices so I put answer with url repository where is placed driver for 1 requested device touchpad/numpad but could be useful others because owner mentioned ZenBook and i use ZenBook and drivers work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to get any docking station working on Linux by installing USB display link drivers:

[How can I get a DisplayLink USB monitor work under Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-work-under-ubuntu)

For me, the toughest part was not installing via the script but finding out that I needed to disable Secure Boot (in UEFI settings).