# Connect second monitor via USB

Tags: usb, display, external-monitor

My Laptop's only HDMI port is broken, so I bought a USB adapter to be able to connect my monitor to my laptop. This worked perfectly fine on Windows, but I switched to Ubuntu recently and it doesn't seem to recognize my monitor. Under "Settings" -> "Displays", Ubuntu only shows available settings for my Laptop's display [(see picture)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L75WH.png).
Is there a way to connect the monitor to my laptop via the USB port?

Comment: Hello. Many of these adapters simply do not work.

Comment: It's probably a DisplayLink adapter, and you need drivers. Can you include the output of `lsusb` in your post to verify this?

Comment: This could help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/6382/how-can-i-get-a-displaylink-usb-monitor-work-under-ubuntu

Comment: @David
output of 'lsusb':
/home/luis/Pictures/Screenshot from 2022-03-18 12-09-05.png